# Change Title Size of Lundt Thesis template

Tags: templates

I am using the [Lundt Thesis template on Overleaf](https://sv.overleaf.com/latex/templates/lund-university-economic-history-master-thesis-template/dfbppztvqzdb) and I cannot seem to find how to change the size of my chapters and titles. Besides, I would like gap between the chapters and the text to be smaller. Can anyone help me out?

This is some of the code from the preamble.

```
\usepackage[hypcap=true,font={small,it}]{caption}

\captionsetup{belowskip=2pt,aboveskip=2pt}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{figure} % lower case default ref
\renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{table} % lower case default ref
\newcommand{\latex}{\LaTeX\xspace}
\newcommand{\mcite}[1]{\textcolor{mycolor}{\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}}
\newcommand{\hcite}[1]{(\textcolor{mycolor}{\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}})}

%%%own preambles
\renewcommand\labelitemi{--}
\renewcommand{\title}{\chapter\title{\large}}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: This does not look like an official template from our university. In the source, it looks like it is the `report` class with just some home made settings (I might be wrong). Probably the usual packages that are used to modify sections and titles can be used.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to add a snippet, but I can't seem to make it work. Really a beginner here. No i'm not submitting the paper to the Lundt university, and besides, the template is unofficial and provided as a sample template on Overleaf. 
About my question: it seems that I need to adjust the section names/titles or whatsoever. See below:
>% Related Work
>  \chapter{Literature Review}
>  \input{Sections/relatedwork}

Comment: @mickep Where can I modify the sections and titles?

Comment: I think you can use a package like for example [sectsty](https://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty?lang=en) to change the setup of sections and titles.